# Mystery Caching Issues

Tags: wordpress, caching

I'm at a loss here and hoping someone has an idea as to what's happening.

**The Issue**
When users add items to their cart and go to check out, the cart displays "empty" even though they have multiple items added.

**What I've Done**
I have removed ALL caching plugins.
I contacted my host to ensure they were also not caching the checkout pages.

**What I've Noticed**
When I look into the file structure there is a folder being created:
*wp-content > cache >* within this folder is a folder named "et" which continues to auto create itself every time I delete it.

Notable points: When I delete or rename this folder, the shopping cart works again, so I know it's a caching issue.

If anyone has any idea what is creating this "cache > et" folder I would be REALLY appreciative.

[image]

Comment: can you share a list of all the plugins.